# Paypal express checkout api contact information not filled

Tags: paypal

Can anybody help me to fill paypal express checkout contact information i.e Email and Phone. I am using api and put the information PAYMENTREQUEST_0_EMAIL and PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOPHONENUM but it didnot

Array
(
    [TOKEN] => EC-73M07454JV691235C
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2014-07-10T07:51:49Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 1fdcf61358cf8
    [ACK] => Success
    [VERSION] => 112.0
    [BUILD] => 11811513
    [REDIRECTURLDIGITALGOODS] => https://www.paypal.com/incontext?useraction=continue&token=EC-73M07454JV691235C
    [REDIRECTURL] => https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&useraction=continue&token=EC-73M07454JV691235C
    [ERRORS] => Array
        (
        )

```
[REQUESTDATA] => Array
    (
        [USER] => 
        [PWD] => 
        [VERSION] => 112.0
        [BUTTONSOURCE] => 
        [SIGNATURE] => 
        [METHOD] => SetExpressCheckout
        [MAXAMT] => 20.00
        [RETURNURL] => 
        [CANCELURL] => 
        [ADDROVERRIDE] => 1
        [LOCALECODE] => FR
        [BRANDNAME] => Demo
        [SOLUTIONTYPE] => Sole
        [LANDINGPAGE] => Billing
        [USERSELECTEDFUNDINGSOURCE] => CreditCard
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT] => 10.00
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE] => EUR
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT] => 0.00
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT] => 0.00
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTONAME] => Didier Gueret
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET] => 4 rue de lÂ´officialitÃ©  BP 19
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCITY] => Valognes
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOZIP] => 50700
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE] => FR
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_EMAIL] => test@test.com
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOPHONENUM] => 408-559-5948
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION] => Sale
        [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0] => Commande
        [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0] => 10.00
        [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0] => 3423423
        [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0] => 1
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT] => 10
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you making sure to include the same parameter in the DoExpressCheckoutPayment request?  If you don't include it there it won't show up in the final transaction details.

Comment: Andrew thank you for your reply. But here i remove it due to security reason. Only the phone filled is not filled otherwise it working ok. You can see I already provide [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOPHONENUM] but it not working.

Comment: Oh, gotcha.  I thought your question was about the empty credential values.  Misunderstood.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: Basically i want that telephone to be filled out. Here is the example imag  http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=35a6duh&s=8